# How to map a list of items in url RequestMapping

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2

I need something like this (pseudo-code, note the []):

```
@RequestMapping("/jpm/[{owners}/{ownersIds}/]{entity}/list")
public ModelAndView doSomething(
        @PathVariable List<String> owners,
        @PathVariable List<String> ownersIds,
        @PathVariable String entity){
   ...
}
```

I need that an url like this

```
/test/1/test2/5/test3/120/something/list
```

map to

```
owners = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
ownersIds = [1,5,120]
```

And

```
/test/1/test2/5/something/list
```

map to

```
owners = ["test", "test2"]
ownersIds = [1,5]
```

Is this possible with regular expressions? how?

**UPDATE 1:**

Optionally, I can try to parse the list of owners by myself, but I cant find the correct expression:

```
@RequestMapping("/jpm/(1){entity}/list")
public ModelAndView doSomething(
        @PathVariable List<String> owners, (1)
        @PathVariable String entity){
   ...
}
```

I need something in (1) that tell me "anything of the form xx/xx/ as many times as you like, optionally none"

Is that possible?

Comment: Is it possible for you to have `/owner1/owner1id/.../ownerN/ownerNid/`? Or can you only have 3?

Answer (score 2):

My first inclination is to tell you to take a look at [Matrix Variables](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables), but I'm thinking you might have already? At any rate, you'd need a different pattern:

```
// First an example request:
// GET /jpm/owners;names=bob,jim,john;ids=1,2,3/entityName/list
@RequestMapping("/jpm/owners/{entity}/list")
public ModelAndView doSomething(
    @MatrixVariable Map<String,List<String>> matrixVariables,
    @PathVariable String entity) {
    // matrixVariables now contains a map with values:
    // "names" => ["bob", "jim", "john"]
    // "ids" => ["1", "2", "3"]
    // ...and then obviously the entity variable resolves to "entityName"
}
```

I typed all that directly here, so I haven't tested it. If I get a chance, I'll try it out and come back and edit appropriately. Hope it helps regardless.

**EDIT AFTER COMMENT**

I guess it's debatable whether or not the use of matrix variables is "RESTful," a term for which there is no official standard, but matrix variables are supported by the likes of Spring and WADL, so that gives them some legs, I guess. Regardless, I believe Spring does not support the use of a "/" in a `@PathVariable` at all, whether or not you use a regular expression. Even if you did go that route, like you said, you'd have to parse the results out to split each item in the resulting list. Instead, why not pass a comma-delimited list as a String and let Spring do the parsing for you?

```
// GET /jpm/owners/bob,jim,john/1,2,3/myEntity/list
@RequestMapping("jpm/owners/{names}/{ids}/{entity}/list")
public String getTest(
    @PathVariable List<String> names, 
    @PathVariable List<String> ids, String entity) {
    // names = ["bob", "jim", "john"]
    // ids = ["1", "2", "3"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's not what I'm looking for as I want to keep it "REST" style. As you have experience, maybe you can help me with an option. See my edit.

Comment: Edited answer for another option.

Comment: Its a matter of semantics. The idea is not to make a list of the "same things" but a parent - child relationship. Something like /car/1/motor/3/screw/list or /car1/screw/list

Comment: Right, I see what you are trying to accomplish, but I don't think it can be done. Just trying to provide alternatives. How are you thinking about doing it?

Comment: At the moment, I'm going to try a mix. Something like /car.1/motor.3/screw/list  it's not the best but is what I get

Comment: Yeah my next suggestion was going to be to just replace the "/" with something else like "_".

Comment: Lets asume I use "_" is there any regexp / PathVariable to get what I need in the form of a map? Map<String,String> owners ... ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There's no way to use backreferences for your @PathVariables, which is what you would need in order to separate n pairs of values into a map.